# Get value from REST API with TCL script

Tags: tcl

I searched option how to do this and cant find. I have web URL, and i have api-key.
I need to write tcl script, which return value from url and api key which i send.
Can you help me please.

Comment: Look into the [rest](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/rest/rest.md) package from tcllib.

Comment: Somebody can write me please example of the  
::rest::parameters url ?key?

Comment: I've never used it and don't have anything set up to be able to test it. Read the documentation carefully, and experiment with it. Good luck!

Comment: I've always just hand-coded everything directly with the http package. It's not too difficult to do…

Comment: Hello again, someone can show me example how i do this, i checked many data and nothing